# Check box information throught Ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an e-mail with the information in a form, the thing is I am not doing correctly the part of the checkbox (without it works perfectly). I am doing this:

HTML:

```
<label for="rimg">Request images</label>//display:none; for this
<span>Request Images</span><input type="checkbox" name="rimg" id="rimg">
```

Jquery (after the ready function):

```
var rimg = 'Images are NOT requested';

if ($('#rimg').val()) {
            rimg  = 'images ARE requested'; //changes what is inside rimg if checked
        }
```

Ajax:

```
//organize the data properly
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone='
        + phone.val() + '&rimg=' + rimg.val() + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message.val());


        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "process.php", 

            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

            //success
            success: function (html) {  
                //things in here
            }
```

PHP:

```
 //Retrieve form data. 
    //GET - user submitted data using AJAX
    //POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
    $rimg = ($_GET['rimg']) ?$_GET['rimg'] : $_POST['rimg'];


    $message = '
        //things in here
        <tr><td colspan="2">' . $rimg . '</td></tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
```

The thing is when the form is sent, it gets it as a POST and not as GET, so, it goes to the .php page. The email that is received hasn't the proper information of the checkbox only an 'on' if it is checked or nothing if is not checked. Hope to be clear with this. Thank you in advance

Comment: instead of doing the name value pair construction yourself you can use `$("#MyFormID").serialize()` also in your name value pair you have not added the rimg value to the rest of the values which is why its not present in your php script.

Comment: check if this is correctly:
`data: data,`

Comment: try this: `data: {data: data},`

Comment: @bruno.karklis he does not need to wrap data into an object

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry I edited it now, i have the val added to the rest of the values, just putted the wrong name here

Comment: what you want to do with it? `rimg.val()` , get the value from checkbox with the id **ring** or get the var ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before:

```
var rimg = 'Images are NOT requested';

if($('#rimg').val()) {
    rimg  = 'images ARE requested'; //changes what is inside rimg if checked
}
```

after:

```
var rimg = 'Images are NOT requested';

if($('#rimg').is(':checked')) {
    rimg  = 'images ARE requested'; //changes what is inside rimg if checked
}
```

Comment: This works, but the php part is not getting the value of rimg. It still puts an "on" if it is checked or nothing if is not checked. Tho, i also goes to other page by the post method, not with the ajax get.

Comment: to use the value from js var ring just put ring instead ring.val()